# Display a session if not null in jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, session

I am trying to display a session only if it is not null in jsp file and I am having issues as shown

```
Syntax error on token "<", invalid Expression 59: 60: <% if(request.getAttribute("message") != null) 61:
```

this is my jsp file where I am checking if the session is not null but it is not working

```
<% if(request.getAttribute("message") != null)
{
    <%=session.getAttribute("message")%>
}
%>
```

Please how do I display a session only if it is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `<%=` construct within a scriptlet block `<%  %>`.  You will have to write Java code to do this:

```
<% if(request.getAttribute("message") != null)
{
  out.println(session.getAttribute("message"));
}
%>
```

Note that the `<%= expression %>` construct is shorthand for `out.println(expression)`.

Comment: I changed this out.println(session.getAttribute("message")); to out.println(request.getAttribute("message")); and it worked

Comment: is there any difference between the two?

Comment: The only difference is the syntax.  The <%= is translated into out.println so there is no runtime difference.

Comment: please can I set the session to be  active only in two seconds from the controller

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you are asking, but it sounds like you want to add additional functionality to this.  I suggest you post that as a new question.  That will allow you to post the relevant code (controller, etc) and to get the attention of a wider audience.

Comment: I am trying to set the maximum time the session should be active using request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(2000); //active for two seconds

Comment: Ok, if there is something that is not working about that, again I suggest you enter that as a new question and provide both the code and specifics about what you have observed.  That will be much more effective that trying to solve it in the comment section of this question.